# Execution order of JS

Tags: javascript, oop, execution

I have following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html data-ng-app="">  
 <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="myJs.js"></script>  
     <script type="text/javascript">  
         function myFunction(){  
             alert("Hello.. internal JS");  
         }  
     </script>  

    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="myJs.js"></script>-->  
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>-->  
</head>  
<body>  

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>  

</body>  
</html>
```

and myJS.js :

```
function myFunction(){ 
    alert("Hello.. External JS");  
}
```

and output is:  Hello.. internal JS.

I would like to know why the last JS gets executed every time? If I shift the  lines to alternate position, the one at the end gets executed.

Thanks

Comment: Because the later definition overwrites the earlier one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the below fiddle to understand it better. If you define the same `function` twice, the bottom most will be called.

http://jsfiddle.net/5dALP/